# Make existing column unique in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have `username` column on `users` table.
I could do somethig like this: `rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq` but I have got `username` column (and I've already run migration).

So how can I make `username` column unique?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not very clear if you want to ensure the values in `username` are unique, or if you want to filter existing values to be unique.

At database level, the way you ensure uniqueness is via indexes. In a migration, create a new unique index for the column.

```
add_index :users, :username, unique: true
```

Please note that the creation will fail if you have duplicates in the current database. In that case, first go to the CLI and remove the duplicates, then run the migration.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like:

```
add_index :table_name, :column_name, :unique => true
```

Or:

```
rails g migration add_index_to_table_name :column_name, :unique => true
```